# MVC RedirectToAction Area with additional slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Is it possible to use the RedirectToAction function inside a controller for this route pattern?

`"User/{username}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Comment: your question is not clear what you are trying to ask?

Comment: i think you should use Attribute routing. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4PK4010514-Understanding-Attribute-Routing-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: it does not change that "User/..." is defined and i don`t know how to redirect there without using directly the URL

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not.  It just has to match a pattern.  Since your hard-coded value "User" comes first and it will build the URL with the controller first, you can just include it in the controller string.  Include other named parameters in the route values, like so:

```
string actionValue;
string usernameValue;
string controllerValue;
string idValue;
RedirectToAction( actionValue, "User/" + controllerValue, new {username = usernameValue, id = idValue} );
```

You're just populating parts of the pattern for matching.  It should build the URL based on your existing routes and it's ability to bind to a particular route based on the named parameter's you've passed to the method.